error HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
I am deploying war on tomcat version 10.1.20 and during deployment getting error HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata.
2024-05-24T02:23:33.783Z  INFO 2555529 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-05-24T02:23:34.119Z  INFO 2555529 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@5001eca6
2024-05-24T02:23:34.122Z  INFO 2555529 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-05-24T02:23:34.214Z  WARN 2555529 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.1.Final.jar:6.5.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.1.Final.jar:6.5.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.1.Final.jar:6.5.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.1.Final.jar:6.5.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.1.Final.jar:6.5.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$1.execute(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:323) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.1.Final.jar:6.5.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$1.execute(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:291) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.1.Final.jar:6.5.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.jdbc.WorkExecutor.executeReturningWork(WorkExecutor.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.1.Final.jar:6.5.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractReturningWork.accept(AbstractReturningWork.java:34) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.1.Final.jar:6.5.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.1.Final.jar:6.5.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:290) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.1.Final.jar:6.5.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.1.Final.jar:6.5.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.1.Final.jar:6.5.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:130) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.1.Final.jar:6.5.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.1.Final.jar:6.5.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.1.Final.jar:6.5.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.1.Final.jar:6.5.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.(Database.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.1.Final.jar:6.5.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:221) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.1.Final.jar:6.5.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.1.Final.jar:6.5.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.1.Final.jar:6.5.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1431) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.1.Final.jar:6.5.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1502) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.1.Final.jar:6.5.1.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
Any idea how to resolve this issue?
I changed db user authentication mode but that did not work.
